# Redirect post without database

Tags: php, javascript, html, xml

I want to get content of a textbox posted on other page without database, means m creating a complaint box, and complaint should be posted on admin page. Every new complain should b at top and others below it. can you please help.

Comment: Why you're so afraid of databaes?

Comment: You have to store the complaints somewhere. Otherwise the complaints will vanish after a page-reload.

Comment: Maybe that's what he actually wants.. not having to read complaints. ;)

Comment: my entire site is on html. if i use database just for dis two pages, den i just know to work in jsp, and it vl make it heavy, nd its not wrth, i hav no idea how to srcpt at server side in php, so m avoiding database connection

Answer (score 2):

When you store some data, you are creating `Data-Base` as well

If you don't want to use SQL or similar (liteSQL, XML file DB,...)
you can use directory structure like this

```
/[year]
/[year]/[month]
/[year]/[month]/[day]
/[year]/[month]/[day]/[exact_timestamp]+[random_hash].[file_extension]
```

and save them in file structure, each complain as standalone text file

Comment: wow... it would be really extensive to load them for the admin to see.

Comment: @0xJoKe depends on how will the admin section be coded and implemented, but anyway it's just idea how to do it without standard DB solution

Comment: given example shows you directory structure, way how to store files with complains on your server. every single complain is in single text file. what else is not clear to you?

Answer (score 1):

It may be best to just have one, delimited file.  Then you only have to read from one place.  Depending on the frequency of your complaints, you may want to have one file per day.

To avoid strange locking issues maybe do something similar to what Marek suggested and temporarily store each complaint in a standalone file.  Then run a CRON to concatenate them every so often